# Urgent trigger on select mysql

Tags: mysql, select, triggers

I have specific demand from my employer. I need to grant INSERT, UPDATE and SELECT access to table A in MySQL to developer_1 and developer_2. They will both insert their own rows into table A, and I will take care which rows are from which developer, through TRIGGER after INSERT. What I need is a way to intercept SELECT statement on any user and to determine which rows can be returned to particular developer. Then I found out that there is no TRIGGER on SELECT! It is really important for me to find the solution because the most important request was that developer_1 cannot see other developers rows. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

just check [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/views.html) for views, it should be able to help you in your situation

Just create a row where you put something to identify each developer ( I guess you already did that)

Then use this identifier to create 2 different views, each will be allowed to one of the developers, knowing that the views are from the same table

Comment: You could use a single view that's defined with `... WHERE owner = SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1)`.

Comment: what do you mean by owner? I tried to add trigger to identify the user that inserted row but got an error "You cannot update row on what insert is executed"..